# admob LARGE_BANNER 0% fill rate

Tags: android, admob

I was having serious problems with my admob match rate on android, so i decided to fine debug what was happening...

Among many problems i found, i noticed the match rate of `LARGE_BANNER` AdSize is near 0%

I did a simple test... create a test layout with all possible banner sizes for smartphones, all with same adunit and loaded all banners exactly same way

the result was only LARGE_BANNER got empty most of the times

Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="b1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="b2" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BANNER" />

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/banner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/smallMargin"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SMART_BANNER" />


            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/smartBanner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/smallMargin"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LARGE_BANNER" />


            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/largeBanner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/smallMargin"
                ads:adSize="LARGE_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/card_ad_unit_id" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE" />


            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/rectangle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/busy_ad_unit_id" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

code:
private void loadAds() {

```
    ((AdView) findViewById(R.id.banner)).loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    ((AdView) findViewById(R.id.smartBanner)).loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    ((AdView) findViewById(R.id.rectangle)).loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    ((AdView) findViewById(R.id.largeBanner)).loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

}
```

result:

[image]

is there any explanation for that